# How to prevent XSS in Spring while loading the page

Tags: spring, spring-security, xss

I found the below mentioned code snippet to handle the XSS while providing the input to the application.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But my application get the records from the DB which gets populated by the third party. And when I show those records on the web page,it starts executing the HTML content. Is there any way I can restrict that also ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is that XML snippet? How do you generate HTML content?

Comment: Hi @holmis83
This XML snippet is inside web.xml. This will filter out the requests but when I am trying to render the data on the UI, I am facing issue. This post is to stop "Stored XSS issue".

Comment: Without more detail it is unlikely that somebody can help you.